# Rearranging table in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I got the following list in Python.

```
v5z 3CD 300
vdz 3CD 100
vqz 3CD 200
vtz 3CD 10
v5z 3C2 22
vdz 3C2 3232
vqz 3C2 338
vtz 3C2 55
v5z 3Cfix 55
vdz 3Cfix 100
vqz 3Cfix 200
vtz 3Cfix 22
```

Though I am wondering how to rearrange it and obtain:

```
vdz 3CD 100
vtz 3CD 10
vqz 3CD 200
v5z 3CD 300
vdz 3C2 3232
vtz 3C2 55
vqz 3Cfix 200
v5z 3Cfix 55
vdz 3Cfix 100
vtz 3Cfix 22
vqz 3Cfix 200
v5z 3Cfix 55
```

I thought of creating the dictionary, but it didn't work out. Any tips?

Comment: Do you mean a list?

Comment: If @MohamedYousof is correct and your data-structure is a `list`, you can solve this problem yourself by studying [the documentation on sorting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)! (You can define an arbitrary function to determine how elements are compared/sorted.) That said, the second list is not a simple re-arrangement of the first list; there are more `3Cfix` entries in the second than the first, for example. How would you describe the relationship between the two "arrangements"?

Comment: yes, it was a list

Comment: What is your sorting criteria? The middle column? What else? Is it a list of strings or list of tuples. Posting a sample of the actual list and not just the print would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

pprint = PrettyPrinter(4).pprint

lst = [
    ['v5z', '3CD', 300],
    ['vdz', '3CD', 100],
    ['vqz', '3CD', 200],
    ['vtz', '3CD', 10],
    ['v5z', '3C2', 22],
    ['vdz', '3C2', 3232],
    ['vqz', '3C2', 338],
    ['vtz', '3C2', 55],
    ['v5z', '3Cfix', 55],
    ['vdz', '3Cfix', 100],
    ['vqz', '3Cfix', 200],
    ['vtz', '3Cfix', 22],
]
sort_index = {
    "vdz3CD100": 0,
    "vtz3CD10": 1,
    "vqz3CD200": 2,
    "v5z3CD300": 3,
    "vdz3C23232": 4,
    "vtz3C255": 5,
    "vqz3Cfix200": 6,
    "v5z3Cfix55": 7,
    "vdz3Cfix100": 8,
    "vtz3Cfix22": 9,
    "vqz3Cfix200": 10,
    "v5z3Cfix55": 11
}

slst = sorted(lst, key=lambda e: sort_index.get("{0[0]}{0[1]}{0[2]}".format(e), 100))
pprint(slst)
```

Try a sort index of your choice - in your case with the last col data.

I have changed the sort_index but Its not a good solution at all

Comment: I have written: sort_index = {'vdz': 0, 'vtz': 1, 'vqz': 2, 'v5z':3}

slst = sorted(lst, key=lambda e: sort_index[e[0]]) Though I still do not know how to obtain the needed list